# Find all the values of real parameter "n"...

Tags: logarithms, parametric

Let $S$ be the set of real solutions for the following equation:$$\log_2(1-x-x^2)=n\log_{1-x-x^2}2+2$$
Determine all the values of real parameter $n$ for which $S\cap(0;{1\over2})\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Do you know a relation between $\log_a b$ and $\log_b a$?

Comment: $\log_ab=\dfrac1{\log_ba}$

Comment: Of course: $log_ab={1\over log_ba}$.

Comment: And so what can we conclude from this?

Comment: Good. Let $y=\log_2(1-x-x^2)$, and note that your equation is now $y+n/y+2$. Right? You can solve that for $y$, which should give you some information. You can also attack the problem from the other end by noting that you are looking for the existence of some $x\in(0,1/2)$ solving the equation, and figuring out what set $1-x-x^2$ must belong to. There's a lot of stuff you can find out, even if the complete solution not immediately obvious!